# Why bitwise complement of a 1-byte variable returns a 4-byte value?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Let's take for example the following two 1-byte variables:

```
uint8_t x1 = 0x00;
uint8_t x2 = 0xFF;
```

When printing the bitwise complement, the result is a 4-byte variable:

```
printf("%02X -> %02X; %02X -> %02X\n", x1, ~x1, x2, ~x2);
00 -> FFFFFFFF; FF -> FFFFFF00
```

I know this can be "solved" using casting or masking:

```
printf("%02X -> %02X; %02X -> %02X\n", x1, (uint8_t) ~x1, x2, (uint8_t) ~x2);
00 -> FF; FF -> 00
printf("%02X -> %02X; %02X -> %02X\n", x1, ~x1&0xFF, x2, ~x2&0xFF);
00 -> FF; FF -> 00
```

But why the non-intuitive behavior in the first place?

Comment: Because `%X` is for `unsigned int`. And no, `uint8_t` is not a 2-byte variable.

Comment: Look up "integer promotions in C" to learn what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many computer processors have a “word” size for most of their operations. E.g., on a 32-bit machine, there may be an instruction that loads 32 bits, an instruction that stores 32 bits, an instruction that adds one 32-bit number to another, and so on.

On these processors, it may be a nuisance to work with other sizes. There may be no instruction for multiplying a 16-bit number by another 16-bit number. C grew up on these machines. It was designed so that `int` (or `unsigned int`) was “whatever size is good for the machine you are running on” and `char` or `short` were fine for storing things in memory, but, once they were loaded from memory into processor registers, C worked with them like they were `int`.

This simplified the development of early C compilers. The compiler did not have to implement your complement by doing a 32-bit complement instruction followed by an AND instruction to remove the unwanted high bits. It only did a plain 32-bit complement.

We could develop languages differently today, but C is burdened with this legacy.

Comment: Even modern processors are not able to work on words of arbitrary sizes. Afaik ARM has 16-bit multiplication (that is impossible to use from C), but has no 8 bit multiplication. Same for 16 and 8-bit addition, subtraction and others. Everything has to be promoted to 32-bit values. Intel is the only architecture that deals with different sizes of values. So this is not a legacy, it how processors are usually built.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the `~` operator to `x1` and `x2`, the values are first subject to integer promotions because `uint8_t` is smaller than an `int`.  The operator is then applied to the promoted value.

So `~x1` is really `~0x00000000` (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`) and `~x2` is really `~0x000000FF` (i.e. `FFFFFF00`).  That's why you get the values you're getting.

Also, the `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int` which it prints as such.

You need to use `%hhx` for the format specifier.  That signifies an `unsigned char` argument.

```
printf("%02hhX -> %02hhX; %02hhX -> %02hhX\n", x1, ~x1, x2, ~x2);
```

Comment: hhX prints `00 -> FFFF; FF -> FF00`

Comment: Are you sure you're using `hhX` and not `hX`?

Comment: @chux It actually might not help in this case.  My implementation defined `PRIx8` as `"x"`.

Comment: @dbush, you're right, apparently hhX on my system yields a `too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]` warning

Comment: `PRIx8` as `"x"` is OK for the implementation.   That is no problem when it prints a `uint8_t`.  This answer is trying to do something different with `printf("%02hhX\n", some_int_with_negative_value);`  which is UB - I think  Hmmmm.

Comment: Your code causes undefined behaviour. `%hhX` must be matched with an argument of type `signed char` or `unsigned char`